# Returning int value from QSqLQuery

Tags: c++, sql, database, oracle, qt

I have a project in university for a desktop app linked to a database, I have an oracle table named CAPTEURS (french word) and I am using QtCreator. I want to get the number of rows in the table so I did this :

```
QSqlQuery p;
p.prepare("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM CAPTEURS");
p.exec();
p.size();
qDebug()<<"*****"<<p.exec();
qDebug()<<"*****"<<p.size();
```

Now `p.exec` is returning `true` while `p.size` returns `-1` which implies `false`.
I tried to run the SQL query manually from the command line and it worked and returned '3' which is the number of lines in my table, help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hi there, can you try `qDebug() << p.lastQuery() << p.lastError();` above *and* below your two existing debug statements and see what you're getting?

Comment: Your query is wrong.  SELECT COUNT(*) over () as num_rows FROM CAPTEURS

Comment: I don't think it's wrong, but the value queried isn't being read.

Comment: @HatemTemimi I can't reproduce `p.size() = -1`. Please provide a [_Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also make sure you [_check the documentation_](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#size) to know what you're expecting... `.size()` gives the number of rows in the result.